# Is it possible to open multiple PDFs/the same multiple times from cmd line?

Tags: batch-file, adobe

I'm attempting to create a simple script file (batch file) that will allow my organization to open multiple pdf documents at specified pages simultaneously. However, I can not seem to open the same pdf multiple times while running the script.

I have tried running the same script that would open the first document on a separate line with a different run command.  I have also tried running a separate batch from the first in order to open the same document a second time with different parameters

```
@echo off
 cd..
  cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader
   start .\Acrord32.exe /A "page=2" "C:\Downloads\doc1.pdf"
   start .\Acrord32.exe /A "page=5" "C:\Downloads\doc2.pdf"
   start .\Acrord32.exe /A "page=3" "C:\Downloads\doc1.pdf"
exit
```

I expected pdf file "doc1" to open twice but with different start parameters.  The first instance would open at page 2, and the second would open at page 3. However, only the first instance of doc1 is ever opened. doc2 opens without consequence at it's expected location.

Comment: Thank you very much LotPings that seems to have done the trick.  Also, for those interested, I had to repeat the /N function in order to open the same document a third time so that the code would be:                                                                       start "" .\Acrord32.exe /A "page=2" "C:\Downloads\test.pdf"


start "" .\Acrord32.exe /A /N "page=1" "C:\Downloads\U_AD_AT4.pdf"


start "" .\Acrord32.exe /N  /A "page=5" "C:\Downloads\test.pdf"

start "" .\Acrord32.exe /N  /A "page=7" "C:\Downloads\test.pdf"

Comment: However, I seem to be running into one more problem.  When I try to open a document a third time using (start "" .\Acrord32.exe /N /N /A "page=7" "C:\Downloads\doc1.pdf") the three documents will open, however the page specification doesn't go through, opening the document at the title page instead (page 1).  I'm also running into errors where the document "couldn't be found" but proceeds to open anyways, it's a little annoying, but inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the `/N` argument from the 2nd instance on, otherwise the 1st one will be reused.
- Added a dummy pair of quotes for the window title
- inserted Timeout just to recognize difference when used without /N´

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\08\29\SO_57715301.cmd
@Echo on
Set "AcroRD=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
if not exist "%AcroRD%" (Echo can't locate "%AcroRD%" & Pause&Exit /B 0)

PushD "C:\Downloads\"

start "" "%AcroRD%" /A    "page=2"  "doc1.pdf"
timeout /T 5
start "" "%AcroRD%" /A /N "page=5"  "doc2.pdf"
timeout /T 5
start "" "%AcroRD%" /N /A "page=3"  "doc1.pdf"
```